# While restarting the compute engine, IP address remains to be static although it should be dynamically assigned

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

While restarting the compute engine, IP address remains to be static although it should be dynamically assigned. Please advice
Details:
master-kdm  us-west4-a

Comment: Do you mean external IP or internal IP? Did you stop VM instance and then start it?

Comment: External IP remains static

Comment: Yes, I just did that but same public IP got assigned but the document says otherwise

Comment: What OS do you use on your VM?

Comment: I have created a Debian machine on GCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to follow you steps and found the same behavior.

Accordingly to the documentation [External IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#externaladdresses):

> Ephemeral external IP addresses are available to VM instances and
>   forwarding rules. Ephemeral external IP addresses remain attached to a
>   VM instance only until the VM is stopped and restarted or the instance
>   is terminated. **If an instance is stopped, any ephemeral external IP
>   addresses that are assigned to the instance are released back into the
>   general Compute Engine pool** and become available for use by other
>   projects. **When a stopped instance is started again, a new ephemeral
>   external IP address is assigned to the instance**.

Please find my steps below:

1. create VM instance:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=us-central1-a --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --subnet=default --network-tier=PREMIUM --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE --image=debian-9-drawfork-v20200207 --image-project=eip-images --boot-disk-size=10GB --boot-disk-type=pd-standard --boot-disk-device-name=instance-1 --reservation-affinity=any
   WARNING: You have selected a disk size of under [200GB]. This may result in poor I/O performance. For more information, see: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#performance.
   Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/us-central1-a/instances/instance-1].
   NAME        ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
   instance-1  us-central1-a  n1-standard-1               10.128.0.3   35.238.213.230  RUNNING
   ```
2. stop VM instance:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances stop instance-1 --zone us-central1-a
   Stopping instance(s) instance-1...done.
   ```
3. start VM instance:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances start instance-1 --zone us-central1-a
   Starting instance(s) instance-1...done.
   Updated [https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/us-central1-a/instances/instance-1].
   Instance internal IP is 10.128.0.3
   Instance external IP is 35.238.213.230
   ```
4. stop VM instance again:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances stop instance-1 --zone us-central1-a
   Stopping instance(s) instance-1...done.
   ```
5. start VM instance again:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances start instance-1 --zone us-central1-a
   Starting instance(s) instance-1...done.
   Updated [https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/us-central1-a/instances/instance-1].
   Instance internal IP is 10.128.0.3
   Instance external IP is 35.238.213.230
   ```

Also, I've tried to start VM instance based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and located at the zone `europe-west3-a` that was terminated for a few days and this VM got the same external IP.

**To solve this issue** you should file an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under this [component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=1162877).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.
I will try to contact GCP support.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Please accept/upvote my answer if it was helpful for you.